# (Notepad++) How to replace a text that has certain word in that line?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have multiple lines like this:

```
{
"source": "Source A",
"target": "Source B",
"idTarget": "3,345",
"strength": "0.5",
"value": "633.5138"
}
{
"source": "Source C",
"target": "Source D",
"idTarget": "1,253",
"strength": "0.7",
"value": "5465.238"
}
```

I want to remove the `.` (dot) in line that has the word `value`, but not on other lines. So it would look something like this:

```
{
"source": "Source A",
"target": "Source B",
"idTarget": "3,345",
"strength": "0.5",
"value": "6335138"
}
{
"source": "Source C",
"target": "Source D",
"idTarget": "1,253",
"strength": "0.7",
"value": "5465238"
}
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^"value":[^.]+\K\.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  "value":  : literally
  [^.]+     : 1 or more not dot
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  .         : a dot
```

**Result for given example:**

```
{
"source": "Source A",
"target": "Source B",
"idTarget": "3,345",
"strength": "0.5",
"value": "6335138"
}
{
"source": "Source C",
"target": "Source D",
"idTarget": "1,253",
"strength": "0.7",
"value": "5465238"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for `\K`: I've not come across it before, as I usually use `sed`, which doesn't support it (even with `-r` option for extended RE).

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your numbers are always formatted like 123.1234, you can use a regular expression to achieve this:

Find what: `"value": "([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)"`
Replace with: `"value": "$1$2"`
Search mode: Regular expression

This search expression will find strings that match `"value": "<numbers>.<numbers>"` and put the numbers that it found in a "capture group", denoted with the round brackets. Both groups (`$1`, `$2`) are then added back into the replaced text without the dot.